# Random color generator and RGB of each instance created

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
func randomCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

extension UIColor
{
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let r = randomCGFloat()
        let g = randomCGFloat()
        let b = randomCGFloat()
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

This is the code i am using in order to produce a random color. My question is the following. Can i get the `r`,`g`,`b` parameters once i call the `randomColor()` function twice? for example

```
`randomColor()` ->>> call
print the r,g,b
`randomColor()` ->>> call
print the r,g,b
```

Since it's a random number generator in order to produce a random color, i am afraid that every time i will try to access one of those variables inside the function i will get different results, since once it will be recalled(?). Help would be appreciated.If there is a different approach feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard `UIColor` method `getRed(_, green:, blue:, alpha:)`:

```
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    UIColor.randomColor().getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)

    print("R: \(r), G: \(g), B: \(g), A: \(g)")
```

Comment: i am a newbie to swift. Are those `&r` considered a pointer? or you just define that you are assigning the Red value to the variable `r`?

Comment: @Korpel Thats from Swift documentation: You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an in-out parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function.

Comment: really thanks for your help. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

It won't be recalled. Once you assign a variable as your randomCGFloat it gets locked in. Reading the value won't randomize it again. The only thing that will randomize it again is calling is saying r = randomCGFloat() again.

To print, just print as you normally would. Maybe `println(NSString("RGB: %.2f %.2f %.2f", r, g, b))` right before your return UIColor line of code.

---

```
func randomCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

extension UIColor
{
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let r = randomCGFloat()
        let g = randomCGFloat()
        let b = randomCGFloat()
        println(NSString("RGB: %.2f %.2f %.2f", r, g, b))
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Comment: Hm that's an approach i didn't think about it. You are actually implementing the `print` inside of the function.